# Place figures and their captions side by side

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I want to place first 2 figures side by side, the next 3 figures in the next line, and the last figure on the third line. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{orign.png}
\caption{Image after preprocessing}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{labeled.png}
\caption{Image labeled by cluster index}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[ width=\linewidth]{3c.png}
\caption{The 3 clusters}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm]{infect.png}
\caption{Infected segment distinguished}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

My  outcome is

[image]

But I want it like

[image]

Comment: If the question is solved then please consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image]

The `minipage` environments are used mainly to constrain the widths of the captions to equal the widths of the associated images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\captionsetup{skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{orign.png}
\caption{Image after preprocessing}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{labeled.png}
\caption{Image labeled by cluster index}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\null

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{3a.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{3b.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{3c.png}
\caption{The 3 clusters}

\bigskip
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{infect.png}
\caption{Infected segment distinguished}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\null
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine several images into one figure I would recommend the [subcaption package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        %\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{orign.png}]
        \rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
        \subcaption{Image after preprocessing}
        %TODO: \label
    \end{minipage}%
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        %\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{labeled.png}
        \rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
        \subcaption{Image labeled by cluster index}
        %TODO: \label
    \end{minipage}%
    \medskip

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        %\includegraphics[ width=\linewidth]{3c.png}
        \rule{.3\linewidth}{.3\linewidth}%
        \quad
        \rule{.3\linewidth}{.3\linewidth}%
        \quad
        \rule{.3\linewidth}{.3\linewidth}%
        \subcaption{The 3 clusters}
        %TODO: \label
    \end{minipage}%
    \medskip

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        %\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm]{infect.png}
        \rule{.3\linewidth}{.3\linewidth}
        \subcaption{Infected segment distinguished}
        %TODO: \label
    \end{minipage}%

    \caption{The entire process}
    %TODO: \label
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The `d` subcaption's width exceeds that of the associated "graph". Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico basically I think it is good to not waste space there but on the other hand it's kind of inconsistent with (a) and (b). I am not aware of conventions regarding this matter. If the caption should not be wider than the image, the width for image and minipage would need to be swapped (so that the width is set in the minipage and the width of the image is set to `\linewidth`). But maybe it would be better to change (a) and (b) (similar to how it is shown in the example in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) on page 4)?